# How to deal with Twilio API SMS errors and invalid phone numbers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

How can I handle errors in the Twilio API in regards to creating an SMS message?

Every time an invalid phone number gets entered, I get a message and a 500 error:

> Unable to create record: The 'To' number is not a valid phone number.

How can I have it redirect back to the home page and simply flash an error notice?

```
class Messager

def initialize
  @account_sid = ENV['ACCOUNT_SID']
  @auth_token = ENV['AUTH_TOKEN']
  @twilio_number = ENV['TWILIO_NUMBER']


  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new @account_sid, @auth_token

end
def send_message(phone_number, movies, username)

  text_message = @client.api.account.messages.create(
    from: @twilio_number,
    to: phone_number,
    body: "Hello movie lover, #{username}!\nHere is your current watch list:\n#{movies}"
    )
  puts text_message.to
end
end
```

I don't need anything fancy, just a redirect to the main page and a quick error message saying their phone number is invalid, not a 500 error page. I'm new to the Twilio API, and I've been troubleshooting this issue for hours.

Comment: [`rescue_from NameOfTheTwilioException, with: :how_to_handle_it`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Or you could just wrap the controller code that calls the `Messenger` in a `begin...rescue...end` block.

Comment: By the way, it's spelt "messenger", not "messager".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you make a request to the Twilio API using the Ruby gem and something goes wrong, the library will throw an error of type `Twilio::REST::RestError`.

In order to avoid a 500 error for your user you should rescue from this error and do something else with your controller. I'm not sure what your controller looks like, so I'll take a guess at what you should do.

First, I'd update the `Messager` class to store the error message if you get one. Also, the `send_message` function should return a boolean to describe whether the message was successfully sent.

```
class Messager
  attr_reader :error

  def initialize
    @account_sid = ENV['ACCOUNT_SID']
    @auth_token = ENV['AUTH_TOKEN']
    @twilio_number = ENV['TWILIO_NUMBER']
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new @account_sid, @auth_token
  end

  def send_message(phone_number, movies, username)
    begin
      text_message = @client.api.account.messages.create(
        from: @twilio_number,
        to: phone_number,
        body: "Hello movie lover, #{username}!\nHere is your current watch list:\n#{movies}"
      )
      return true
    rescue Twilio::REST::RestError => error
      @error = error
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in your controller you can call `send_message` and do different things if the message is successful or otherwise.

```
class MessagingController < ApplicationController
  def create
    messager = Messager.new
    if messager.send_message(params[:phone_number], current_user.movies, current_user.username)
      # Success! Message sent!
      # Now do what you were going to do with the successfull result
    else
      # Boo, something happened.
      Rails.logger.warn("#{messager.error.code}: #{messager.error.message}")
      # Redirect or render an action with an error here.
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you so much! When I deployed to Heroku, a wrong phone number just redirects to the user page, so I was (sort of) able to avoid that problem. However, I want my app to handle errors appropriately. 

I appreciate a big-time developer like yourself helping out a small-time developer ;-) Cheers!

Comment: Just glad to have helped out. Hope the rest of the app goes well!